# Nodejs Express - Why won't my static file be served?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Ive been looking a all kind of posts and just can't understand my mistake. Whatever I do, my css file is just not being served.Does anyone know why?

test/server/app.js:

```
            var express = require('express');
            var path = require('path');
            var app = express();

            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'browser')));
            var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
            app.listen(PORT, function() {
                console.log('Server is listening!');
            });
```

test/browser/index.html:

```
            <head>
                <base href="/" />
                <title>Test</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/style.css" />
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

                <script src="app.js"></script>
                <script src="js/app.controller.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <p>hello world</p>

            </body>
            </html>
```

My css file is in test/public/style.css

Comment: have you tried with  href="../public/style.css" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your app code can be found in `test/server/`, which means that `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` will yield (the absolute path value for) `test/server/public`, which is not where your CSS file is located.

Instead, you'd want to use this:

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')`
```

Which would make it point to `test/public/`.

However, this only partly solved the problem, because you're also telling Express that `test/public/` is the root directory of the static resources, meaning that your stylesheet's URL is `/style.css`, not `public/style.css`.

If you want to keep the `public` prefix (which you probably do), you need to use this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));
```

And in your HTML, be sure to use absolute paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/style.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I changed it to path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')` and to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/style.css" />. When that didn't work I used app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'))); and again nothing works

Comment: actually i does work now. I don't know why but i had to quit and start running the server again..only then did it show the changes

Comment: @javascript2016 well, yeah, that's generally how Node apps work: when you change the code, you need to restart the app.

Comment: actually, I don't. So far any change I make updates without me having to restart it, thats why was confused

Comment: @javascript2016 client-side changes (like changing values in CSS) will require only a browser reload, but server-side changes (like the ones proposed here) require that the app be restarted.

Comment: Oh okay, understand it now! Thank you!!